# affix not working with bootstrap 4 in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a working code which fixes the table header when we scroll the page vertically down. I used affix in it and bootstrap version 3.3.7.

But now I see that the latest version for bootstrap is 4.0.0 and when I try to convert my code to work with 4.0.0, it does not seem to work.

I searched google and found out that affix is not supported in the latest bootstrap versions, I did tried a few things but not able to fix header now .

Can anyone please help me out.

Below is my code :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
  .affix {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
      background-color: #fff;
      align-content: flex-end;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: calc(1170px - 30px); /*container width - 30px padding*/
        word-wrap: break-word;

  }

    th,td {
        width:6.67%;  /*100% number of Cloumn*/
    }

  .lin
    {

    color:windowtext;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /*width:20px;*/
    }

  .sol
    {

    color:windowtext;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /*width:20px;*/
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>sssssssssdhhdhdhd dddddd for Hello sssssssdd</h2>

  <table class="table table-striped">

    <thead data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">

      <tr>      
      <th>Current Rel<br/>
        Arssstecture<br/>
        fitrtyr<br/>
        of OS
        </th>

        <th>aupporz <br/>
            asdins</th>

        <th>aussorz <br/>
            znds</th>

        <th><br/>
        a34<br/>
        (IAas)<br/>
        31
        </th>

        <th>Pinux<br/>
        a86_64<br/>
        63
        </th>

        <th><br/>
        <br/>
        xCC
        </th>

         <th><br/>
        <br/>
        abc 
        </th>

        <th><br/>
        sd51<br/>
        (sdanium)<br/>
        64
        </th>

        <th>
        sdhetr<br/><br/>
        32
        </th>

        <th>
        sdhetr<br/><br/>
        64
        </th>

        <th>
        pun/aassssu<br/>
        aaaaa<br/>
        64<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        pun<br/>
        a86_64<br/>
        14<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        cIX<br/>
        weakiPC<br/>
        63<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        aP<br/>
        aA <br/>
        aISC<br/>
        34<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        pandows<br/>
        a16<br/>
        31<br/>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="font-size:11px">
      <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Regards

Comment: iam open to use something other than affix which fixes my table header. Please suggest.

Comment: What JS code did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: sticky;` as recommended in [Bootstrap 4 Migration Guidance](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/). just remember to use one of top, bottom, right or left properties on the element otherwise it will be rendered like a `position: relative;` element.

```css
    th,td {
        width:6.67%;  /*100% number of Cloumn*/
    }

  .lin
    {

    color:windowtext;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /*width:20px;*/
    }

  .sol
    {

    color:windowtext;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /*width:20px;*/
    }

.fixed-header th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>sssssssssdhhdhdhd dddddd for Hello sssssssdd</h2>

  <table class="table table-striped">

    <thead class="fixed-header">

      <tr>      
      <th>Current Rel<br/>
        Arssstecture<br/>
        fitrtyr<br/>
        of OS
        </th>

        <th>aupporz <br/>
            asdins</th>

        <th>aussorz <br/>
            znds</th>

        <th><br/>
        a34<br/>
        (IAas)<br/>
        31
        </th>

        <th>Pinux<br/>
        a86_64<br/>
        63
        </th>

        <th><br/>
        <br/>
        xCC
        </th>

         <th><br/>
        <br/>
        abc 
        </th>

        <th><br/>
        sd51<br/>
        (sdanium)<br/>
        64
        </th>

        <th>
        sdhetr<br/><br/>
        32
        </th>

        <th>
        sdhetr<br/><br/>
        64
        </th>

        <th>
        pun/aassssu<br/>
        aaaaa<br/>
        64<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        pun<br/>
        a86_64<br/>
        14<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        cIX<br/>
        weakiPC<br/>
        63<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        aP<br/>
        aA <br/>
        aISC<br/>
        34<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        pandows<br/>
        a16<br/>
        31<br/>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="font-size:11px">
      <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```